# Scroll bar at the top of my activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have a RelativeLayout and a recyclerview.

I add CoordinatorLayout and AppBarLayout to make both scroll.

It works. The problem is the toolbar is only at the recyclerview and when user scroll down and up it will stop at recyclerview top needing another scroll top to see relativeLayout.

To sum up I want the scroll to be on the top of activity (starting in relative layout left side) not only in the recyclerview. Any ideas how can I add the scroll at the side of my relativelayout?

my xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/header"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageViewProfile"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:cropToPadding="false" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Do you want your relative layout to scroll up until gets hide?

Comment: @JonathanAste no, I just want the scrollbar to be at the left of my relative layout. it is appearing only in my recyclerview. The problem is that when user scrolls down the recyclerview and go up again the scroll will stop at the recyclerview top, not at the relative layout as I wanted. To see the relative layout user needs to scroll upper.

Comment: So your problem is that the recyclerview scroll overlaps the relativeLayout scroll?

Comment: yeah, that is it.

Comment: Try to put your entire relative layout and recycler inside a ScrollView